# How can i detect which number sum to my output sum in c#?

Tags: c#

I have this number:

```
  Int64[] arr1 = new Int64[] { 28811251, 19374713, 9602311, 217578282, 461715268, 3983660, 231978436, 9791904, 11206597, 62907620, 156311365, 7527222, 8340887 };
```

and i want to write c# windows application to find which two number sum out equal`sum=984724000` ?

Comment: [See this solution](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21405/maximum-sub-array-problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < arr1.Length; j++)
{
    if (i == j) continue;

    Int64 sum = arr1[i] + arr1[j];
    if (sum == 984724000)
        Console.WriteLine(arr1[i].ToString() + "+" + arr1[j].ToString())
}
```

Comment: can i ask why `if (i == j) continue;`

Comment: because you are adding the same value with itself

Comment: Stackoverflow: "This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer." Actually, All I wanted to do was add a + and a ; to make it valid compilable c#, but stack overflow doesn't allow less than 6 character edits :)

Comment: what if the value was `492362000`. then the sum with it self will be `984724000`. do a calculate your self. actually it may worked for OP as he didn't have `492362000`. but that's a bug in your algorithm.